# On critical values of a linear function $g:SO_2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider map $g:SO_2\times \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, $g(A,v)=Av$, where $A\in SO_2$ is an orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrix and $v\in \mathbb R^2$ is a $2$-vector.

Show that $0$ is a critical value.

**My try;**

If we paremetrize $SO_2$ by  \begin{array}{|cc|}
\cos(t) & \sin(t)  \\
-\sin(t) & \cos(t)  \\
 \end{array}  then we will get paremetrization of $SO_2\times \mathbb R^2$ by $r(t,u,v)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),-\sin(t),\cos(t),u,v)$ for $t,u,v\in \mathbb R$.

Hence, $\text{Rank}(J(g\circ r))=\text{Rank} J(g)$ where $J(f)$ denotes the Jacobian matrices of $f$. Thus, I found that $0$ is not a critical value which is wrong according to question.

Comment: I think you're right. In fact, this map is a submersion.

Comment: Indeed, for any linear action, the restriction to $\{I\}\times\Bbb R^2$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix) induces an isomorphism of tangent spaces.